# PHP regexp strange behavior

Tags: php, regex

I was developing a simple regex to parse part of a URL, the regex must be able to capture part of the url in a named group, there are only a few allowed characters (a-z0-9 and -) if other characters are present the regexp must fail for the given string and no capture will be done.

But as you can see on the screenshoot when the regexp find a % sign it stops, and capture the part before it (if it is longer than two chars), the result is the same without the word boundaries (\b).

I can't understand why % is acting like \n and the engine is capturing the previous chars and stopping the % is not in the allowed list of chars so it should fail for that string... or not?

I've tried in the actual PHP code as well, with the very same result.

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

Actual PHP code:

```
if (preg_match('/fixed_url_part/\b(?P<codename>[a-z0-9-]{2,})\b', $url, $regs)) {
    return $regs['codename'];
}
```

Comment: Exact code in the question would be useful. It looks though your placeholder simply looks for alphanumeric chars, which excludes `%`.

Comment: I edited the answer with the code, but the point is, why with % it capture the previous chars and with, for example _ on the string it fails? why is not failing with %?

Comment: Without the end anchor (as pointed out by @Halcyon) your pattern only matches "*until*" it finds no more matching characters. And the word `\b` boundary holds true when encountering `%`.

Comment: Thanks @mario, i did not know that % was a word boundary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't tell it to match the full line. Add `$` to have it match the end.

```
^/fixed_url_part/\b(?P<codename>[a-z0-9\-]{2,})\b$
^-- match start of line                          ^-- match end of line
```

Comment: keep `-` also in group as OP wants.

Comment: I'd also add `^`, just in case. (I guess that `abc/fixed_url_part/def` should fail.)

Comment: With the end of string anchor ($) it works fine, but what i want to know is why with % in the string the regexp capture part of it, when it shoud fail (as it fail if the character is _ instead of %).

Comment: I think it's because of `\b` (word boundary). `%` is considered a word boundary whereas `_` is not. So `%` triggers the `\b` causing the match.